# Warning - count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have install PHPMyADMIN and it is giving WARNING.

```
Warning in ./libraries/sql.lib.php#601
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
Backtrace

./libraries/sql.lib.php#2038: PMA_isRememberSortingOrder(array)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#1984: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse(
...
./index.php#53: include(./sql.php)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the bug of `Phpmyadmin [sql.lib.php]`. Closing Bracket is Missing - `)`
This is the easiest way to fix is to just copy and paste the bellow line in your terminal and then check your `PHPMyAdmin`

```
sudo sed -i "s/|\s*\((count(\$analyzed_sql_results\['select_expr'\]\)/| (\1)/g" /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php
```

If you are doing manually then it might give `500 server internal error`.

[image]